# Sparql insert query failing

Tags: sparql

I am trying to run the below sparql query to insert data to my graph, but it's failing with the error: Error 400: Bad Request.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX person: <http://example.com/data/person#>
PREFIX contact: <http://example.com/data/contact#>

INSERT
{ 
  person:p4595 contact:email "test1@example.com" ;
               contact:mobile "99483-43843" .
    
  person:p6593 contact:email "test2@example.com" ;
               contact:mobile "55351-56477" .
}
```

I have validated all the IRIs and triples are correct. Not sure why the query is failing.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#insertData

Comment: Online parsing service: http://www.sparql.org/update-validator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `insert` syntax is incorrect. You should use either `insert data` or `insert {...}` followed by `where {}` (with empty `{}`). I have not run the query, but it should be something like this:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX person: <http://example.com/data/person#>
PREFIX contact: <http://example.com/data/contact#>

INSERT DATA
{ 
  person:p4595 contact:email "test1@example.com" ;
               contact:mobile "99483-43843" .
    
  person:p6593 contact:email "test2@example.com" ;
               contact:mobile "55351-56477" .
}
```

Comment: Ohh! Silly mistake!! Thanks for pointing it out.